# width of unordered lists going out of width of the content div

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, accordion

I want to design a dropdown vertical menubar like accordion menu. I took reference from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

I am getting problem setting the width of the list which is flowing out of the widht of the accordion button. Please see the image attached.

```
<div id="aside">
                    <button class="accordion">Registration</button>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="OPDRegister.aspx">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a href="CustomerRegistration.aspx">Bottoms</a></li>
                            <li><a href="CustomerRegistration.aspx">Footwear</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <button class="accordion">Txn Configuration</button>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="OPDRegister.aspx">Configuration</a></li>
                            <li><a href="CustomerRegistration.aspx">Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="CustomerRegistration.aspx">General</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <button class="accordion">Reports</button>
                    <div id="foo" class="panel">
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="OPDRegister.aspx">End Day</a></li>
                            <li><a href="CustomerRegistration.aspx">Summary</a></li>
                            <li><a href="CustomerRegistration.aspx">User Wise</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Css

```
#aside {
            float: left;
            width: 215px;
            margin-right: 0;
        }

    button.accordion {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
        width:97%;
    }

    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    button.accordion:after {
        content: '\002B';
        color: #777;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    button.accordion.active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    div.panel.show {
        opacity: 1;
        max-height: 500px;  
    }

    .submenu{
         list-style-type: none;
    }
```

How can I set the width of the unordered lists same as the accordion width and make the contents of the unordered list left justified same as that of the content of accordion?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`button.accordion` has width 97% change it to 100%

Comment: how can I make the contents of the ul left justified, I mean at the same vertical line with the content of accrodion button? Please help.

Comment: @user4221591 have the same padding on `.panel` as `.accordion` and remove the default padding the browser applies to a `<ul>`.

Comment: well you need to remove padding from `.submenu` element and `div.panel`

`.submenu { padding: 0}` and `div.panel { padding:0}`

this will give you zero padding .. now increase value according to your need

now i see that you have padding on button .. so to match it you can do 

`div.panel { padding : 10px }`